# Why atmospheric pressure exist related?

Tags: gravity, pressure, atmospheric-science, diffusion

My Question is That?
There are a variety of gases that are in our atmosphere. They all together create an atmospheric pressure. why this pressure exist I mean look at outside the earth there is nothing more than a huge empty space. Is Gravity pull sufficient to bind this pressure together ? or Is there any other factor responsible to create this pressure ? this whole is nothing different from an open-air pressure cooker.

Answer (score 1):

Gravity holds the atmospheric gases to the earth.  Very light gases like helium near the top of the atmosphere can gain enough energy from a collision with a heavier molecule to exceed the escape velocity. The pressure at any level is caused by the weight of the gasses above.

Comment: the weight of a column of air one square inch in area stretching from the surface of the earth all the way up into space is 14.7 pounds.